# Replacing the VGA cable of an old CRT monitor

Tags: display, vga

I understand the fact that VGA monitors come with an non replaceable VGA cable since one pair of male and female connectors have been eliminated in the signal path, the connection to the video source should have a more consistent impedance and be more reliable.
Now just in case **I wish to replace the VGA cable of my old CRT monitor with a new one due to damages then is it possible?and if yes how to do it??**

Comment: In very short you need to get a new cable and connector, cut the old cable (Or even disassemble to reach original soldering points) and solder everything together. If you need more details you need to share what you've tried and ask more specific question.